# How to delay execution of a controller (angularjs) till an external JS file loads?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, youtube-iframe-api

I'm working on a Youtube API based project in which I've already bootstrapped angular.
I'm encountering a problem when I need to call an external JS to load the iFrame API js file first and then allow angular to work on it on specific routes.

The problem is that Youtube iFrame API calls **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()** function just after loading and this function needs an html element with **id = 'player'**, and I want to load this iFrame API only in certain views. Hence **iFrame API can't be called from index** file because it would not find any element with **id='player'**.

But if I call it from one of the views itself, then the API takes time to create a **YTPlayer object**. Meanwhile, a controller would have called for it and didn't find it.

How do I go about this?

I'm still learning the concept of Resolve, so I'm not sure how can I leverage it in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

This is common problem. Some of the JS stuff does not mix well with angular. What I often do is that I add "extension" methods to a JS file.

1) Write a directive which is wrapper around a Youtube API(you need to override onYouTubeIframeAPIReady with your own callback so you can actually TARGET any dom element with concrete id, instead of only one.)

2) In your directive, use requireJS to pull in reference for your CUSTOM external js file.

```
require(['youtubeAPI', function(youtubeAPI){
     // register directive
      .directive('externalYoutube', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          transclude: true,
          scope: {},
          templateUrl: 'my-dialog.html',
          link: function (scope, element) {
            youtubeAPI.loaded = function(){
               youtubeAPI.wrap(element);
            }; 
          }
        };
      })]);
```

the usage would be something like

```
<external-youtube />
```

in html.

Comment: I got it working by loading the API earlier(in index file) and then calling the function at an appropriate time.